# MS SQL 2012 remove repeated characters from only Right and Left

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need stripe repeated characters from left and right only.

From:

```
,,,,2000001,2000002,2000003,2000004,2000005,2000006,,,,,
```

To:

```
2000001,2000002,2000003,2000004,2000005,2000006
```

Comment: Which `DBMS` you are using

Comment: I'am using MS Sql 2012

Answer (score 4):

Cheat with trim:

```
REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(fld, ',', ' '))), ' ', ',')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `LEFT`, `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX` string functions

Try this

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(500) = ',,,,2000001,2000002,2000003,2000004,2000005,2000006,,,,,' 

SELECT LEFT(intr, Charindex(',,', intr) - 1) as Result
FROM   (SELECT Substring(@str, Patindex('%[0-9]%', @str), Len(@str)) AS intr) a
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using just `REPLACE` :) - so funny:

```
select replace(replace(replace(',,' + YourField + ',,', ',,', '.'), '.,', ''), '.', '')
```

The character `.` should not be present in the value of your field, so you can choose any other character meeting that requirement.

This approach is even usable when your field contains spaces (then you cannot play the trick with `RTRIM` and `LTRIM`).